# position fixed header not working on my website

Tags: jquery, html, css

This my website https://bed-sheet-2.myshopify.com/ ,Added fixed position header css

```
.site-header{z-index:110;position:fixed;width:100%;left:0;}
```

It's not working on my website, How solve this problem. I search across stackoverflow, no solve.

Comment: Please replicate the problem or post the necessary code here, instead of giving link to your site..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao header section class site-header , i added position:fixed , not working

Comment: you can try to use !important    ... position:fixed !important;

Comment: I updated position:fixed !important; , not working http://imgur.com/mbPrbTK

Comment: any reason `is-moved-by-drawer` is added for `PageContainer` ?

Comment: Thank  Vitorino fernandes, Updated, I disable is-moved-by-drawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `.site-header{z-index:110;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;}`
You need to add the `px` and a `top` value.

Comment: I update top value, not working fixed header. Check the website

Comment: Ok, it should work. Take a look at this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ug37w32n/1/, as you will see, it works on there.  So, you must not be selecting the right HTML element, or something is overriding it.

Comment: Jeff, I update the code, not working position:fixed, check the image  http://imgur.com/mbPrbTK

Comment: I see. What I answered (and what's in my JSFiddle) should work.

Comment: Im using Google chrome, any problem in Browser?

Comment: I'm using Safari, and it doesn't work either.  Did you take a look at my JSFiddle?

Comment: What Shopify Theme are you using?

Comment: Updated disable is-moved-by-drawer

Comment: Your welcome @LindaCapellini! I'm glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Your Welcome @LindaCapellini!

Answer (score 0):

try this. margin need to set 0px auto
.site-header{width:100%; margin:0px auto; position: fixed; top:0px}

Comment: I updated on google chrome Inspect `margin:0px auto; `, no header fixing

Answer (score 0):

Demo for that:https://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/JLKbn

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var  mn = $(".main-nav");
        mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
        hdr = $('header').height();

        $(window).scroll(function() {
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
            mn.addClass(mns);
            } else {
            mn.removeClass(mns);
            }
        });
    </script>

.main-nav{
  position: relative;
}
.main-nav {
  background: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 150;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
header,.main-nav-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

<nav class="main-nav">
  <a href="#">Nav Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Nav Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Nav Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Nav Link 4</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to make your answer more valuable.